# Laravel access JSON object in controller

Tags: laravel

I have this array in the controller after the submitted form holds in variable `$product`.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "nancy",
        "cost": 34,
        "quantity": 0,
        "barcode": 12345,
        "category_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-07-05T16:04:10.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-09T04:06:09.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "jk",
        "cost": 100,
        "quantity": 2,
        "barcode": 147258,
        "category_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-07-08T20:34:56.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-18T13:09:16.000000Z"
    }
]
```

How can I access the properties in objects like `id`, `name`, `barcode` ?

Comment: I think you actually mean to say you have an array of objects and as such the output is actually: `[0 => '{"id":2,"name":"nancy","cost":34,"quantity":0,"barcode":12345,"category_id":2,"created_at":"2020-07-05T16:04:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-09T04:06:09.000000Z"}', 1 => '{"id":5,"name":"jk","cost":100,"quantity":2,"barcode":147258,"category_id":2,"created_at":"2020-07-08T20:34:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-10-18T13:09:16.000000Z"}'];
` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it as array of array.

```
$products = json_decode($products, true);  // Return array of array.

foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product['name']; 
}
```

Comment: You are converting it into array and then accessing it as object. It will not work

Comment: it assosiative array

Comment: in PHP json_decode convert json data into PHP associated array
For Ex: $php-array= json_decode($json-data, true);
print_r($php-array);

Comment: what i'm saying is after converting `$products` to array, you can't access properties like `$product->name`, now it should be `$product['name']`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php by using `true` as the second argument, you are converting it to an associative array. Arrow syntax `->` does not work anymore

Comment: Yeah , You are Right .

Answer (score 1):

Just decode it, use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$products = json_decode($products, true);  // When TRUE, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays

foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product['id']; 
}
```